# How to handle callbacks in if else condition in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I am using [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) in my project for working with asynchronous JavaScript. Here is a situation for which I am not able to handle callback.

```
async.each(array1,function(arr1,callback1){
  async.each(array2,function(arr2,callback2){
     if(condition){
       //process1;
       callback2();
     }else{
      //process2;
      callback2();
     }
  },function(error){
     if(error){ 
      console.log("error in callback 2",error)
     }else{ 
      callback1()
     }
  })
},function(error){
   if(error){ 
     console.log("error in callback 1",error)
   }else{ 
     //process after callback
   }
})
```

My problem is that during this process if condition is not true always therefore in above case I get callback already called error.

I have to handle both conditions. I tried to find solution on internet but couldn't find any solution. How do I solve this problem. Please help.

Comment: You may like to use `async.eachSeries` rather than `async.each` because each does not have callback argument as you are accepting callback1 and callback2. Please have a look doc http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each

Comment: I removed callback2() from both if and else condition and then called callback2() only once above if condition. It worked. I don't know why?